# How to stop the current domain from being prepended to the URL during jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, google-chrome-devtools

Im trying to make an ajax call using an absolute url. But the url is automatically being prepended with the current domain and hence giving me a 404. How can I stop the current domain from prepending to the URL.

$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "www.xxxx.org" + path + ".zzzz.json",

```
            . 
            .
            // rest of the code }
```

here  path is /etc/xxx/yyy/etc

The error I'm getting is:
GET http://yyyyy.xxx.org/www.xxx.org/etc/xxx/yyy/zzzz.json 404.

If anyone has any idea about solving this problem, please help. Thank you.

Comment: You need to add `http://` before your url.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URLs without a leading scheme are treated as relative URLs from the origin of current page. (This is the same behavior for the values in `<a href="..."`> links.)

You must use a scheme, e.g., `http://www.xxxx.com/...` instead of `www.xxxx.com/...`